# Deploy Lemoon to Azure

Tags: azure-web-app-service, lemoon

I have created a website in Lemoon and deployed it to Azure. This leads to the following:

> Mindroute.Core.BootStrapper|Startup failed.
>   System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

Searching the internet says this is related to not being able to reach the license server of Lemoon. How can this be fixed. It should be possible because Lemoon is available as cms in Azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried something that in my opinion should have worked to no avail. I created a Lemoon site in Azure via the gallery. Published the site from development keeping the publicKey in de web.config already created (not really necessary because its the same). Linked the site to my existing database and copying the value from the settings table. Still the same error.
Creating a lemoonsite in an existing SQL server is also not working and i refuse to use a free version of SQL server in Azure. I'm afraid if it's not going to work today I'll leave Lemoon. Too much hassle for little benefit.

Comment: Having tried to install it on Azure lead to an error on the test server where I can no longer run the application.  If anyone is considering using Lemoon, I would strongly advise to contact Lemoon (formpipe) for the possibilites or impossibilities before starting to use this CMS